# Error displaying image in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I know there are some relevant questions, but none of them covers my subject.

So, I have a web application using jsp, java, postgresl and apache tomcat 7.0.27.0 embedded inside NetBeans (as a plugin) and in the web directory of the project I have an 116.jpg image

When I m displaying this image like that : `< img src='116.jpg' alt='title' />`

It is being displayed correctly. Now, I want to display an image that I just uploaded and it went to a directory where it is relative to that as this : One directory up, then folder 'data' and finally folder 'img'. So,  technically, `< img src='../data/img/117.jpg' alt='title' />`  This, however, is not being displayed. Moreover...

I want to do it automatically . In here `<%= sUploadFName %>` I have the name of the image that is being uploaded by the user (e.g. 865.jpg ).

So, I would want something like that in order to work:
`< img src='../data/img"<%= sUploadFName %>"' alt='title' />` and the image should appear normally.

Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the contents of the `web`(except for WEB-INF and META-INF) folder are publicly accessible via urls, so your uploaded image must reside in `web` or in a child of it.

If you are storing the images in another directory then you would have to create a class that extends the `HttpServlet` and map it to an URL, say `/myapp/uploads/*` (`/myapp` is the ContextPath) whenever that url is visited such as `/myapp/uploads/119.jpg` obtain the file name using `request.getPathInfo()` method and perform the required validation (file exists, permisions, etc), then read the file and serve it via the `HttpServletResponse`'s output stream.

Alternatively you could map tomcats [Default Servlet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html) to the `/uploads/*` url pattern if no permission validation is required.

The source for your image tag would be `<img src="/myapp/uploads/119.jpg" alt="Image" />`

Here is an example servlet:

```
package servlets;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;

public class StreamServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final String WINDOWS_UPLOAD_DIR = "C:\\Projects\\Data\\img";

    /**
     * Serve the images from the specified dir.
     *
     * @param req
     * @param resp
     * @throws ServletException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
              throws ServletException, IOException {

        String fileName = req.getPathInfo().substring(1);
        File imageFile = new File(WINDOWS_UPLOAD_DIR, fileName);

        OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(imageFile);

        IOBridge(is, os);
        os.flush();
        Close(is, os);
    }

    /**
     * Bridge data between an input and output stream.
     *
     * @param in  The input stream.
     * @param out The output stream
     * @throws IOException if there's an error.
     */
     private static void IOBridge(InputStream in, OutputStream out) 
             throws IOException {

         byte data[] = new byte[1024];
         int readCount = 0;
         while ((readCount = in.read(data, 0, readCount)) != -1) {
             out.write(data);
         }
      }

     /**
      * Close some closeables
      *
      * @param closeables The closeables to be closed.
      */
     private static void Close(Closeable... closeables) {
          for (Closeable c : closeables)
              if (c != null)
                  try {
                      c.close();
                  } catch (IOException ioe) {
                      try {
                          c.close();
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                  } finally {
                        try { 
                             c.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                 }
         }
    }
```

Then in your `web.xml`, you would add:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StreamServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.StreamServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StreamServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploads/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

[Java Servlet Speciciation 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1359476655_e0cf0f58b07658640e2d1c705a6b86a8)

Comment: Triztian I may know java but I am not that good in jsp and I have a deadline pushing. Maybe another solution would be for me to copy the images from the other directory back in it(because I cannot change the directory in which the images are being stored right now). Is it easier?

Comment: I wrongly assumed that you are using tomcat, are you using it?

Comment: Yes, I am using embedded Apache Tomcat as a NetBeans plugin Triztian

Comment: I have two questions about that. I wrote the servlet and I modified web.xml. But about   private static final String LINUX_UPLOAD_DIR = "/var/www/myapp/uploads";  the root directory /var before var what are you assuming it is here? I have the real path C:\Projects\Project\data\img in my computer so I am trying to give private static final String LINUX_UPLOAD_DIR = "/Project/data/img" here. Am I correct; And secondly, then this LINUX_UPLOAD_DIR will be my root directory to call the images? E.g if I have 123.jpg inside img folder I will 
img src="/123.jpg" alt="Image"/> 
and I am done?

Comment: The source for the `img` tag will stay the same as in the answer, as you can see I just modified the constant, the path in the constant is completely different from the *url* of the `img` tag.

Comment: The source for my image tag then should be <img src="C:/Projects/Project/data/img/117.jpg" alt="Image" /> ? But I am typing this and I cannot get the image. I cannot understand what this /myapp/uploads/* is and how is it mapped? It's a last thing I suppose, sorry for all those questions, I would appreciate it if you told me just that. Greetings.

Comment: What I mean, is that I must be giving the wrong directory inside the .jsp to call the image. I have tried both <img src="C:/Projects/Project/data/img/117.jpg" alt="Image" /> and    <img src="Project/data/img/117.jpg" alt="Image" /> and they don't work. What will be my root directory when I call the image? Just like before, Web directory? Or I will give an absolute path starting from C:/ ? Thanks.

Comment: In my answer I state what the `src` attribute of the `img` tag should be, which is `src="/myapp/uploads/119.jpg` (it is before the code samples), I also mention that the `/myapp` is the context path of your web application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23587/discussion-between-george-kourou-and-triztian)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't with jsp, but with wrong url for image.

If image isn't displayed for

```
< img src='../data/img/117.jpg' alt='title' />
```

that mean that either you are wrong about location of picture to page, or there is some interceptor. Perhaps image is in file system organized like you wrote, however that doesn't mean that url is also organized in this way. Check in web.xml if there is servlet-mapping for images or something similar. Bottom line is if plane img isn't working don't fix jsp :) first you need to find out correct url for image and after it will be easy